# Handling Related objects in Hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Model:

```
namespace org.acme.model

enum CustomerSegment {
o P
o E
}

asset Account identified by Account_No {
  o String Account_No
  --> Customer Account_Holder
  o String Account_Type
  o Integer Balance
}

participant Customer identified by Customer_ID {
  o String Customer_ID
  o String First_Name
  o CustomerSegment Customer_Segment
}

transaction UpdateCustomerSegment{
  --> Account A
  --> Customer C
}

transaction changeBalance{
  --> Account A
  o Integer newBalance
}

  event UCS_Event{
    -->Account A
    o String oldsegment
    o String newsegment
  }

event BalanceChangEvent{
  -->Account A
  o Integer oldbalance
  o Integer newbalance
}
```

Script:

```
  /**
     * Place an order for a vehicle
     * @param {org.acme.model.UpdateCustomerSegment} ucs - the transaction that calculated Customer Segment
     * @transaction
     */

function UpdateCustomerSegment(ucs)
{
  var CustomerID=ucs.C.Customer_ID;
  var oldCS=ucs.C.Customer_Segment;

  if(ucs.A.Balance>3000)
    ucs.C.Customer_Segment="E"
  else
    ucs.C.Customer_Segment="P"

  var cust = getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.model.Customer')
  .then(function(participantRegistry){
  return participantRegistry.update(ucs.C);
  })

  .then(function(){
    //Emit Event
    var event_g= getFactory().newEvent('org.acme.model','UCS_Event');
    event_g.A=ucs.A;
    event_g.oldsegment=oldCS;
    event_g.newsegment=ucs.C.Customer_Segment
    emit(event_g);
  })

  return cust;
}
```

What I need to do is - 
Pass only the Account No. to the transaction.
the transaction should fetch the appropriate Customer - where customer ID is same as Account's Account Holder, and update the Customer's Customer Segment

which I am unable to do. is it even doable. I am new, so not sure.

in the above transaction I am passing both the Account No. and Customer ID

2nd Question
Can we update a Participant & Asset both in the same transaction ? if yes how.

3rd Question:
how to call one transaction from within another.

Answer (score 1):

Your model looks good, now you need to write a Transaction Processor function that subscribes to `UpdateCustomerSegment` transaction and that implements your logic to change the customer segment of the customer, and then persist the customer.

The `basic-sample-network` includes a similar simple transaction processor:

```
/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {org.acme.sample.SampleTransaction} tx The sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */
function sampleTransaction(tx) {

    // Save the old value of the asset.
    var oldValue = tx.asset.value;

    // Update the asset with the new value.
    tx.asset.value = tx.newValue;

    // Get the asset registry for the asset.
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleAsset')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {

            // Update the asset in the asset registry.
            return assetRegistry.update(tx.asset);

        })
        .then(function () {

            // Emit an event for the modified asset.
            var event = getFactory().newEvent('org.acme.sample', 'SampleEvent');
            event.asset = tx.asset;
            event.oldValue = oldValue;
            event.newValue = tx.newValue;
            emit(event);

        });

}
```

Comment: Hey Dan, Thanks for the response. I have gone through the Basin network. I have a few questions though.

1. Can we update a Participant Details via a Transaction ? in the above example say for 'Tobias' I want to change the `Customer Segment` to some other value by checking his Balance is more than a certain condition.

Help me with this :
`transaction updateCustomerSegemnt{
--> Account A}`

Comment: `function updateCustomerSegemnt(tx) {

    var balance= tx.A.balance;

    if(balance>3000)
    {
 Account Holder of Account A's (i.e Tobias) Customer Segment shall update to 'E'
    }

    return getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.sample.Customer')
        .then(function (participantRegistry) {
            return participantRegistry.update(tx.?);
        })

        .then(function () {
            var event = getFactory().newEvent('org.acme.sample', 'SampleEvent');
            ...
            emit(event);

        });

}`

Comment: 2. How to update get the Customer(participant) back from the Account(Asset)[input to transaction]
relation is Account_Holder of account is a customer.

3. How do we update a Participant Registry - 
assuming is Customer was a input to the Transaction as
`--> Customer C`
Tried updating the Participant using the below codes before, doesnot seems to work for me.

`return getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.sample.Customer')
        .then(function (participantRegistry) {
            return participantRegistry.update(tx.C);
        })`

Comment: I think you want to update `tx.A.Account_Holder` but it would be much easier to read this if you updated your question with the latest code and the stack traces / logs for any errors you are seeing.